# How can i get value with javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript

i have following text

```
http://www.mydomain.com/#!/account/?id=17
```

and i am getting # with window.location.href which is giving me

```
#!/account/?id=17
```

now i want to extract that id value with preg_match or any regular expression because that id value is dynamic...
actually i am loading data with jquery ajax...please let me know the exact expression for getting value of id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"#!/account/?id=17".match(/id=(.*)/)[1]
```

---

**EDIT**

```
var result = window.location.href.match(/id=(.*)/);
```

- match returns an array with two positions:

  - result[0] = all matched string ("id=17")
  - result[1] = first group match ("17")

Comment: but how can i match account/?id=17 as a whole

Comment: "#!/account/?id=17".match(/#\!(.*)/)[1]

Comment: "#!/account/?id=17".match(/#\!\/(.*)/)[1]